# expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, image-processing, error-handling, compiler-errors, linked-list

my debugger comes up with that error (expected primary-expression before ')' token ) whenever I try to compile. Here's the bit of code with the error.

```
#define threshold 40 //threshold intensity

using namespace std;
using namespace cimg_library;

void RegionGrow (CLinkedList<struct structure> &ListName, CByteImage &Img, uint32_t uRow, uint32_t uCol)
{
 if (Img.Element (uRow+1, uCol) > threshold)
 {
  ListName.AddToTail(structure);
  Img.Element (uRow+1, uCol) = 0;
  RegionGrow (ListName, Img, uRow+1, uCol);
 }
}
```

Anyone know about C linked list? or error-handling? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: That's a *large* chunk of code. Which *specific* line is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: @KrishnachandraSharma What?!? You don't need a `;` there.

Comment: 1. Where exactly is the error? 2. What's `Img.Element`?

Comment: Your _debugger_ gives you an error when you _compile_? Wow... Just... Wow...

Comment: Okay. What you on about?

Answer (score 3):

In line:

> ListName.AddToTail(structure);

*structure* is a data type *not* an object.

Perhaps you intended to write something like:

> ListName.AddToTail(ListName);

**EDIT:** also, you are using the terms Debugger, C Linked List and Error handling in wrong context. Refer to some good C++ book: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/770118)